# Reading a MongoDB database using Chatscript

Tags: mongodb, chatscript

I am making a BOT that must interact with a database in MongoDB, but I don't know how to call the HTTP methods of my API, which is already working with the database, but I don't know how I can connect, I want to be able to use that data within the bot conversations.

For example:

```
u: ()
         ^jsonundecodestring(%$) $name , I am a BOT from $center , I am writing to confirm your scheduled appointment for $day at $hour with $doc from $esp , would you like to confirm $data this appointment? To answer use the words Confirm or Reject
```

All that data (the $something ones) should theoretically be able to get out of the database, but I still can't figure out how to call it.